# How do I get rid of the overlap of gridlines and tick mark labels?

Tags: plotting

I wish to include the plot generated by the following Mathematica code

```
Plot[1/Root[-3 - 8 #1 Tan[a/2] - 3 Tan[a/2]^2
               + #1^4 (1 + Tan[a/2]^2) + #1^2 (-9 + 3 Tan[a/2]^2) &, 2],
  {a, 0, 2 Pi},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  Ticks -> {{0, Pi/6, Pi/3, Pi/2, 2 Pi/3, 5 Pi/6, Pi, 7 Pi/6, 4 Pi/3, 
    3 Pi/2, 5 Pi/3, 11 Pi/6, 2 Pi}, {0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 
    0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1, 1.125, 1.25, 1.375, 1.5}}, 
  GridLines -> {{Pi/6, Pi/3, Pi/2, 2 Pi/3, 5 Pi/6, Pi, 7 Pi/6, 4 Pi/3, 
    3 Pi/2, 5 Pi/3, 11 Pi/6, 2 Pi}, {0, 1/8, 2/8, 3/8, 4/8, 5/8, 6/8, 
    7/8, 1, 9/8, 10/8, 11/8, 12/8}}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dashed]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

in an article I'm writing.  I don't like how the GridLines overlap the axis labels however.  I searched around a bit for a solution but I'm no Mathematica expert and I can't work it out.  Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: One small remark, you could use `Ticks -> {Range[0,2Pi,Pi/6],Range[0,1.5,0.125]}` and the same idea for your GridLines - does the same but is clearer.

Comment: @Ronny thanks, as I said I'm not really very good at Mathematica.  I tend (in things related to Mathematica) to learn the bare minimum required to get what I want :).

Comment: Just added the plot graphics so people can see what ails you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting `PlotRangePadding` to zero is probably the easiest option, but as an alternative you could draw the grid lines by hand using `ProLog`:

```
ticks = {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6], Range[0, 1.5, .125]};
Plot[1/Root[-3 - 8 #1 Tan[a/2] - 
     3 Tan[a/2]^2 + #1^4 (1 + Tan[a/2]^2) + #1^2 (-9 + 
        3 Tan[a/2]^2) &, 2], {a, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 Ticks -> ticks,
 Prolog -> 
  Style[{Gray, Dashed, 
    Line[{{#, 0}, {#, 1.4}}] & /@ Rest[ticks[[1]]], 
    Line[{{0, #}, {2 Pi + .2, #}}] & /@ Rest[ticks[[2]]]}, 
   Antialiasing -> False]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is my favourite, since Prolog is something I should have thought of to use.  I wasn't certain of the syntax but I did at least know it existed!  About the axes: I really don't like the decimal point after the 1, so will write that out as before.  I had no idea it would work for the radians though.  Cheers!

Answer (score 12):

An alternative to kguler's approach is to set `PlotRangePadding` to zero on the relevant sides.

> Notice I've simplified your grid and tick specifications using `Range`. The y-axis ticks need to be machine-precision (1/8. increment) or they will actually be fractions. If you don't like the decimal point after the 0 and 1, then the full listing as in your question is needed for the ticks (but not the gridlines).

```
Plot[1/Root[-3 - 8 #1 Tan[a/2] - 
     3 Tan[a/2]^2 + #1^4 (1 + Tan[a/2]^2) + #1^2 (-9 + 
        3 Tan[a/2]^2) &, 2], {a, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6], Range[0, 12/8, 1/8.]}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6], Range[0, 12/8, 1/8]}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dashed], 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, Scaled[0.02]}, {0, Scaled[0.02]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I've learnt PlotRangePadding... had no idea what it did before (surely not designed to solve this problem).

Comment: Stick around, there are plenty of little-known corners of Mathematica's graphics functionality that get explored on this site! And a few German-speaking Aussies.

Answer (score 7):

**Adjusting the lengths of ticks**

Building on @Verbeia's solution,
you may want to shorten the tick mark length by using the third parameter of `Ticks`. This leaves both a negative and positive tail for each tick (see pic 1, below):

```
Plot[1/Root[-3 - 8 #1 Tan[a/2] - 3 Tan[a/2]^2 + #1^4 (1 + Tan[a/2]^2) + #1^2 (-9 + 
    3 Tan[a/2]^2) &, 2], {a, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6] /. {n_?NumericQ -> {n, n, 0.01}}, 
              Range[0, 12/8, 1/8.] /. {n_?NumericQ -> {n, n, 0.01}}}, 
    GridLines -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/6], Range[0, 12/8, 1/8]}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dashed], 
    PlotRangePadding -> {{0, Scaled[0.02]}, {0, Scaled[0.02]}}]
```

[image: ticks3]

Or you may want to get rid of ticks altogether, using ticks of zero length by using
`/.{n_?NumericQ -> {n, n, 0}}` instead of `/.{n_?NumericQ -> {n, n, 0.01}}`.

[image: ticks4]

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 Plot[1/Root[-3 - 8 #1 Tan[a/2] - 3 Tan[a/2]^2 + #1^4 (1 + Tan[a/2]^2) + #1^2 (-9 + 
    3 Tan[a/2]^2) &, 2], {a, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75, 0.875, 1, 
 1.125, 1.25, 1.375, 1.5}, None}, 
 {{Pi/6, Pi/3, Pi/2, 2 Pi/3, 5 Pi/6, Pi, 7 Pi/6, 4 Pi/3, 
 3 Pi/2, 5 Pi/3, 11 Pi/6, 2 Pi}, None}}, 
 GridLines -> {{0, Pi/6, Pi/3, Pi/2, 2 Pi/3, 5 Pi/6, Pi, 7 Pi/6, 
 4 Pi/3, 3 Pi/2, 5 Pi/3, 11 Pi/6, 2 Pi}, {0, 1/8, 2/8, 3/8, 4/8, 
 5/8, 6/8, 7/8, 1, 9/8, 10/8, 11/8, 12/8}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dashed]]
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks, although I really didn't want to move the axes.

Comment: @GlenWheeler, you need to add `PlotRangePadding->0`; or, better yet, just use `PlotRangePadding` as in Verbeia's answer.