# Plot a piecewise function with black and white disks marking discontinuities

Tags: plotting, piecewise, discontinuity

Let's say I'd like to plot `Sign[x + 0.5]`:

```
Plot[Sign[x + 0.5], {x, -1, 1}]
```

*Mathematica* will give this:

[image: plot of the function]

This plot does not show very clearly the value of `Sign[x + 0.5]` at `x = -0.5`: is it 1? is it -1? No, it's 0, but there is no indication of which it is on the plot. This is what I'd like to achieve:

[image: plot with discontinuity markers]

(I used Paint to add the markers.) How can I make it *Mathematica* do it?

Comment: Related [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5770/13) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11361/13)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

*Update 2015-7-13:* `PlotPiecewise` now handles discontinuities of non-`Piecewise` functions. (It basically did this before, but required the head to be `Piecewise` or contain a built-in discontinuous function, like `Sign`.  All I did was brainlessly wrap a function in `Piecewise`.  I also had to rewrite some of the `Reduce`/`PiecewiseExpand` code.  One of the more complicated examples, which used to expand to a number of integer cases, kept the integer parameter instead of expanding; in another (not shown), the `Ceiling` of a complicated function was no longer expanded into a `Piecewise` function.

*Update:* `PlotPiecewise` now automatically tries to convert a non-`Piecewise` function into one using `PiecewiseExpand`.  `PiecewiseExpand` will also do some simplification, such as factoring and reducing a rational function; to avoid that, pass a `Piecewise` function directly.  `PlotPiecewise` will not alter the formulas in a `Piecewise`.  Note, however, that *Mathematica* automatically reduces `x (x - 1) / (x (x - 2))` but not `(x^2 - x) / (x (x - 2))`.

---

A while back I wrote a function `PlotPiecewise` to produce standard pre-calculus/calculus graphs of [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html) functions.  It works a lot like plot.  It evolved from time to time, but it's nowhere near a complete package.  For instance, `PlotPiecewise` is not `HoldAll` like `Plot`, because it was convenient for a certain use-case and my typical uses didn't need it either.  There are a few options, but not really a complete set.  Another limitation is that it was intended for rather simple piecewise functions, of the type one might ask students to graph by hand.  For instance, it uses `Reduce` and `Limit` to find asymptotes but doesn't check if they worked; one should really check.  It won't handle functions that are too complicated or that cannot be expanded as `Piecewise` functions.

I'll offer it, since it seems to do what the OP asks and I've already written.  It seems worth sharing.  I hope the community appreciates it.  Code dump at the end.

---

**OP's example**

*Update: There is no longer a need to expand `Sign`.  `PlotPiecewise` will automatically do it.**

```
PlotPiecewise[Sign[x + 1/2], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**More Examples**

```
PlotPiecewise[
 Piecewise[{
   { 1 / (-1 + 2 x),      0 < x <= 1},
   { 2,                       x == 0},
   { -x,                      x < 0},
   { (2 - x) / (-3 + x),  1 < x < 4},
   { -6 + x,              4 < x}},
  Indeterminate],
 {x, -2, 6.5},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-2.8, 3.1}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[-3, 6], Range[-4, 3]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
g[t_] := Piecewise[{
    {Abs[1 + t], -2 <= t < 0},
    {2, t == 0},
    {2 - Cos[Pi*t], 0 < t < 2},
    {(-16 - 12*t + t^3)/(8*(-4 + t)), t >= 2}},
   Indeterminate];
PlotPiecewise[g[t], {t, -2, 6}, PlotRange -> {-2, 9}, DotSize -> Offset[{3, 3}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update: New cases handled**

The updated code can do these things:

```
PlotPiecewise[Exp[(Sign[Sin[x^2]] - 3/4) x/2] - 1, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
PlotPiecewise[
 Piecewise[{
   {(-1 + 3*x)^(-1), -1 < x <= 1},
   {Tan[Pi*x], 1 < x < 11/2}},
  Indeterminate],
 {x, -2, 6.5}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {-2.8, 3.1}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[-3, 6], Range[-4, 3]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**New examples (2015-7-13)**

From [Is there any way to reveal a removable singularity in a plot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88071/is-there-any-way-to-reveal-a-removable-singularity-in-a-plot):

```
PlotPiecewise[(2^x - 2)/(x - 1), {x, -2, 2}, 
 "DotSize" -> Offset[{3, 3}], 
 "EmptyDotStyle" -> 
  EdgeForm[Directive[ColorData[97, 1], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A similar one:

```
PlotPiecewise[(2^x - 2)/(x^2 - 1), {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Code dump**

Here is an update.  It is I hope written in a somewhat better style.  I also took the opportunity to add a couple of features.  `PlotPiecewise` will automatically apply [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html), and if it produces a `Piecewise` function it will plot it.  It will also handle a wider range of conditions in a `Piecewise` function.  There is a bit more error checking, and some error messages have been added.  It is still not `HoldAll`.  Since Mr.Wizard prodded me to improve the code, I tried to keep it so that it would work in V7.

```
ClearAll[PlotPiecewise, PlotPiecewise`plot, PlotPiecewise`init, 
  PlotPiecewise`solve, PlotPiecewise`expand, 
  PlotPiecewise`annotatedPoints, PlotPiecewise`boundaryPoints, 
  PlotPiecewise`interiorPoints, PlotPiecewise`sowAnnotations, 
  PlotPiecewise`inDomain];

PlotPiecewise::usage = 
  "PlotPiecewise[Piecewise[...], {x, a, b}, opts]";
PlotPiecewise::limindet = 
  "Limit `` is not numeric or infinite at ``";
PlotPiecewise::nonpw = 
  "Function `` is not a Piecewise function or did not expand to one";

PlotPiecewise`debug::debug = "``";
PlotPiecewise`debug::plot = "``";
PlotPiecewise`debug::annotation = "``";
PlotPiecewise`debug::limit = "``";
PlotPiecewise`debug = 
  Hold[PlotPiecewise`debug::debug, PlotPiecewise`debug::plot, 
   PlotPiecewise`debug::annotation, PlotPiecewise`debug::limit];
Off @@ PlotPiecewise`debug;

Options[PlotPiecewise] = 
  Join[{"DotSize" -> Automatic, "EmptyDotStyle" -> Automatic, 
    "FilledDotStyle" -> Automatic, "AsymptoteStyle" -> Automatic, 
    "BaseDotSize" -> Offset[{2, 2}],
    "AdditionalPoints" -> {},                         (* 
    addition pts to annotate *)

    "PiecewiseExpand" -> Automatic,           (* which fns. 
    to expand *)
    "ContinuousEndpoints" -> Automatic},(* eval. 
   formula, not limit *)
   Options[Plot]];
Options[EmptyDot] = Options[FilledDot] = Options[Asymptote] =
    Options[PlotPiecewise`plot] = Options[PlotPiecewise`init] =
      Options[PlotPiecewise];

 (* graphics elements *)
Clear[EmptyDot, FilledDot, Asymptote];
EmptyDot[pt_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; 
   OptionValue["EmptyDotStyle"] === None := {};
FilledDot[pt_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; 
   OptionValue["FilledDotStyle"] === None := {};
Asymptote[pt_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; 
   OptionValue["AsymptoteStyle"] === None := {};
EmptyDot[pt_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := {White, 
   OptionValue["EmptyDotStyle"] /. Automatic -> {}, 
   Disk[pt, 
    OptionValue["DotSize"] /. 
     Automatic -> OptionValue["BaseDotSize"]]};
FilledDot[pt_, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] := {OptionValue["FilledDotStyle"] /. 
    Automatic -> {}, 
   Disk[pt, 
    OptionValue["DotSize"] /. 
     Automatic -> OptionValue["BaseDotSize"]]};
Asymptote[x0_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := {Dashing[Large], 
   OptionValue["AsymptoteStyle"] /. Automatic -> {}, 
   Line[Thread[{x0, OptionValue[PlotRange][[2]]}]]};


PlotPiecewise`$inequality = 
  Greater | Less | LessEqual | GreaterEqual;
PlotPiecewise`$discontinuousAuto = Ceiling | Floor | Round | Sign;
PlotPiecewise`$discontinuousAll = 
  Ceiling | Floor | Round | Sign |(*Min|Max|Clip|*)UnitStep | 
   IntegerPart |(*FractionalPart|*)Mod | Quotient | UnitBox | 
   UnitTriangle | 
   SquareWave(*|TriangleWave|SawtoothWave*)(*|BernsteinBasis|\
BSplineBasis|Abs|If|Which|Switch*);
PlotPiecewise`$discontinuous = Ceiling | Floor | Round | Sign;

 (* auxiliary functions*)

(*  causes Conditional solutions to expand to all possibilities;
    (arises from trig eq, and C[1] -- perhaps C[2], etc?
 *)
PlotPiecewise`expand[cond_Or, var_] := 
  PlotPiecewise`expand[#, var] & /@ cond;
PlotPiecewise`expand[cond_, var_] := 
  Reduce[cond, var, Backsubstitution -> True];
PlotPiecewise`solve[eq_, var_] /; 
   MemberQ[eq, PlotPiecewise`$discontinuous, Infinity, 
    Heads -> True] := 
  PlotPiecewise`solve[# == C[1] && C[1] ∈ Integers && 
      And @@ Cases[eq, Except[_Equal]], var] & /@ 
   Cases[eq, PlotPiecewise`$discontinuous[e_] :> e, Infinity];
PlotPiecewise`solve[eq_, 
   var_] := {var -> (var /. #)} & /@ 
    List@ToRules@
      PlotPiecewise`expand[
       Reduce[eq, var, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True], 
       var] /. {False -> {}}; 

 (* limit routines for handling discontinuous functions,
   which Limit fails to do *)
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
PlotPiecewise`nlimit[f_?NumericQ, var_ -> x0_, dir_] := f;
PlotPiecewise`nlimit[f_, var_ -> x0_, dir_] := 
  NLimit[f, var -> x0, dir];
PlotPiecewise`limit[f_, var_ -> x0_, dir_] /; 
   MemberQ[Numerator[f], PlotPiecewise`$discontinuous, Infinity, 
    Heads -> True] :=
  Module[{y0, f0},
   f0 = f //. (disc : PlotPiecewise`$discontinuous)[z_] /; 
       FreeQ[z, PlotPiecewise`$discontinuous] :> disc[
       With[{dz = Abs[D[z, var] /. var -> N@x0]}, 
        Mean[{z /. var -> N@x0, 
          z /. var -> x0 - 0.1 Last[dir]/Max[1, dz]}]]
       ];
   Message[PlotPiecewise`debug::limit, {f0, f, var -> x0, dir}];
   Quiet[Check[y0 = PlotPiecewise`nlimit[f0, var -> x0, dir], 
     Check[y0 = Limit[f0, var -> x0, dir], 
      If[! NumericQ[y0], y0 = Indeterminate]]], {Power::infy, 
     Infinity::indet, NLimit::noise}];
   y0
   ];
PlotPiecewise`limit[f_, var_ -> x0_, dir_] :=
  Module[{y0},
   Quiet[Check[y0 = f /. var -> x0, 
     Check[y0 = Limit[f, var -> x0, dir], 
      If[! NumericQ[y0], y0 = Indeterminate]]], {Power::infy, 
     Infinity::indet}];
   y0
   ];

PlotPiecewise`$reverseIneq = {Less -> Greater, Greater -> Less, 
   LessEqual -> GreaterEqual};
PlotPiecewise`reverseIneq[(rel : PlotPiecewise`$inequality)[
    args__]] := (rel /. PlotPiecewise`$reverseIneq) @@ 
   Reverse@{args};
PlotPiecewise`inDomain[] := 
  LessEqual @@ PlotPiecewise`domain[[{2, 1, 3}]];
PlotPiecewise`inDomain[dom_] := LessEqual @@ dom[[{2, 1, 3}]];

  (* annotatedPoints -- 
     returns list of abscissas to be "annotated"
     with dots/asymptotes
   boundaryPoints --
      returns list of boundaries numbers between \
pieces
   interiorPoints --
      returns list of points where the \
denominator is zero
 *)
PlotPiecewise`annotatedPoints[allpieces_, domain_, 
   additionalpoints_] :=
  DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@Join[ 
     PlotPiecewise`boundaryPoints[allpieces, domain],
     PlotPiecewise`interiorPoints[allpieces, domain],
     additionalpoints
     ];

PlotPiecewise`boundaryPoints[allpieces_, domain : {var_, _, _}] :=

  With[{conditions =
     DeleteDuplicates[
      Equal @@@ 
       Flatten[Last /@ 
          allpieces /.
         {HoldPattern@
            Inequality[a_, rel1_, b_, rel2_, 
             c_] :> {PlotPiecewise`reverseIneq[rel1[a, b]], 
            rel2[b, c]}, (rel : PlotPiecewise`$inequality)[a_, b_, 
            c_] :> {PlotPiecewise`reverseIneq[rel[a, b]], rel[b, c]}}
        ]]},
   Message[PlotPiecewise`debug::annotation, conditions];
   var /. 
     Flatten[ (* deletes no soln {}'s *)

      PlotPiecewise`solve[# && PlotPiecewise`inDomain[domain], 
         var] & /@ conditions,
      1] /. var -> {} (* no BPs in domain *)
   ];

PlotPiecewise`interiorPoints[allpieces_, domain : {var_, _, _}] := 
  MapThread[
   Function[{formula, condition},
    Flatten[
     {With[{solns = 
         PlotPiecewise`solve[
          Denominator[formula, Trig -> True] == 
            0 && (condition /. {LessEqual -> Less, 
              GreaterEqual -> Greater}) && 
           LessEqual @@ PlotPiecewise`domain[[{2, 1, 3}]], 
          PlotPiecewise`var]},
       PlotPiecewise`var /. solns /. PlotPiecewise`var -> {}
       ],
      If[MemberQ[Numerator[formula], PlotPiecewise`$discontinuous, 
        Infinity, Heads -> True],
       With[{solns = 
          PlotPiecewise`solve[
           Numerator[formula] == 
             0 && (condition /. {LessEqual -> Less, 
               GreaterEqual -> Greater}) && 
            LessEqual @@ PlotPiecewise`domain[[{2, 1, 3}]], 
           PlotPiecewise`var]},
        PlotPiecewise`var /. solns /. PlotPiecewise`var -> {}
        ],
       {}
       ]}
     ]],
   Transpose@allpieces
   ];

 (* sowAnnotations - Sows irregular points, tagged with three ids;
     "filled"    \[Rule] {x,y};
     "empty"     \[Rule] {x,y};
     "asymptote" \[Rule]  x;
 *)
PlotPiecewise`sowAnnotations[allpieces_, 
   domain : {var_, a_, b_}, {}] := {};
PlotPiecewise`sowAnnotations[allpieces_, domain : {var_, a_, b_}, 
   points_List] :=
  (Message[PlotPiecewise`debug::annotation, 
    "sowAnn" -> {allpieces, points}];
   PlotPiecewise`sowAnnotations[allpieces, domain, ##] & @@@ 
      Partition[{If[First[#] == a, Indeterminate, a]}~Join~#~
        Join~{If[Last[#] == b, Indeterminate, b]}, 3, 1] &@
    SortBy[points, N]);

PlotPiecewise`sowAnnotations[allpieces_, domain : {var_, _, _}, 
   xminus_, x0_?NumericQ, xplus_] :=

  Module[{y0, yplus, yminus, f0, fminus, fplus},
   f0 = First[
     Pick @@ MapAt[# /. var -> x0 & /@ # &, Transpose@allpieces, 
        2] /. {} -> {Indeterminate}];
   Quiet[y0 = f0 /. var -> N@x0, {Power::infy, Infinity::indet}];
   If[xminus =!= Indeterminate, (* xminus ≠ left endpoint *)
    fminus = 
     First[Pick @@ 
        MapAt[# /. var -> Mean[{xminus, x0}] & /@ # &, 
         Transpose@allpieces, 2] /. {} -> {Indeterminate}];
    yminus = PlotPiecewise`limit[fminus, var -> x0, Direction -> 1];
    ];
   If[xplus =!= Indeterminate, (* xplus ≠ right endpoint *)
    fplus = First[
      Pick @@ MapAt[# /. var -> Mean[{x0, xplus}] & /@ # &, 
         Transpose@allpieces, 2] /. {} -> {Indeterminate}];
    yplus = PlotPiecewise`limit[fplus, var -> x0, Direction -> -1];
    ];
   If[Abs[yminus] == Infinity || Abs[yplus] == Infinity, 
    Sow[x0, "asymptote"]];
   If[NumericQ[y0],
    Sow[{x0, y0}, "filled"]];
   Message[
    PlotPiecewise`debug::annotation, {{x0, y0, f0}, {xminus, yminus, 
      fminus}, {xplus, yplus, fplus}}];
   Sow[{x0, #}, "empty"] & /@ 
    DeleteDuplicates@DeleteCases[Select[{yminus, yplus}, NumericQ], y0]
   ];


 (* initialization of context variables *)

PlotPiecewise`init[f : HoldPattern@Piecewise[pieces_, default_], 
   domain : {var_, _, _}, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  (PlotPiecewise`domain = 
    SetPrecision[domain, Infinity];
   PlotPiecewise`var = var;
   PlotPiecewise`allpieces =
    If[default =!= Indeterminate,
      Append[pieces,(* 
       add True case to pieces *)
       {default, 
        If[Head[#] === Not, Reduce[#], #] &@
         Simplify[Not[Or @@ (Last /@ pieces)]]}],
      pieces] /. {formula_, HoldPattern@Or[e__]} :> 
      Sequence @@ ({formula, #} & /@ List[e]);
   PlotPiecewise`$discontinuous = 
    OptionValue[
      "PiecewiseExpand"] /. {Automatic -> 
       PlotPiecewise`$discontinuousAuto, 
      All -> PlotPiecewise`$discontinuousAll, None -> {}};
   Message[PlotPiecewise`debug::debug, "f" -> f]
   );

 (* The main plotting function *)

PlotPiecewise`plot[f : HoldPattern@Piecewise[pieces_, default_], 
   domain : {var_, a_, b_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=

  Block[{PlotPiecewise`var, PlotPiecewise`domain, 
    PlotPiecewise`allpieces, PlotPiecewise`$discontinuous},
   (* INITIALIZATION:
     PlotPiecewise`var;
      PlotPiecewise`domain;
      PlotPiecewise`allpieces;
      PlotPiecewise`$discontinuous
   *)
   PlotPiecewise`init[f, domain, opts];
   Message[PlotPiecewise`debug::plot, 
    "allpieces" -> PlotPiecewise`allpieces];

    (* POINTS OF INTEREST *)

   With[{annotatedpoints = PlotPiecewise`annotatedPoints[
       PlotPiecewise`allpieces,
       PlotPiecewise`domain,
       OptionValue["AdditionalPoints"]], 
     plotopts = 
      FilterRules[{opts}, 
       Cases[Options[Plot], Except[Exclusions -> _]]]},
    Message[PlotPiecewise`debug::plot, 
     "annotatedpoints" -> annotatedpoints];
     (* ANNOTATIONS *)
    With[{annotations = Last@Reap[
         PlotPiecewise`sowAnnotations[
          PlotPiecewise`allpieces,
          PlotPiecewise`domain,
          annotatedpoints],
         {"asymptote", "empty", "filled"}]},
     Message[PlotPiecewise`debug::plot, 
      Thread[{"asymptote", "empty", "filled"} -> annotations]];
      (* PROCESS PLOT *)
     With[{exclusions = Join[
         If[OptionValue[Exclusions] === None, {}, 
          Flatten[{OptionValue[Exclusions]}]],
         PlotPiecewise`var == # & /@ 
          Flatten[First@annotations]](*can't we use annotatedpoints?*)},
      With[{curves = 
         Plot[f, domain, 
          Evaluate@Join[{Exclusions -> exclusions}, plotopts]]},
       Show[curves,
        Graphics[{ColorData[1][1], EdgeForm[ColorData[1][1]], 
          OptionValue[PlotStyle] /. Automatic -> {}, 
          MapThread[
           Map, {{Asymptote[#, PlotRange -> PlotRange[curves], 
               opts] &, EmptyDot[#, opts] &, FilledDot[#, opts] &}, 
            If[Depth[#] > 2, First[#], #] & /@ annotations}]}]]]]
     ]]
   ];

 (* The user-interface *)

PlotPiecewise[f : HoldPattern@Piecewise[pieces_, default_], domain_, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] := PlotPiecewise`plot[f, domain, opts];

 (* tries to expand f as a Piecewise function *)

PlotPiecewise`pweMethods = {"Simplification" -> False, 
   "EliminateConditions" -> False, "RefineConditions" -> False, 
   "ValueSimplifier" -> None};
PlotPiecewise[f_, domain : {var_, a_, b_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   Block[{PlotPiecewise`graphics},
     (* restrict var in PiecewiseExpand/Reduce*)
   With[{a0 = If[# < a, #, # - 1/2] &@Floor[a],
     b0 = If[# > b, #, # + 1/2] &@Ceiling[b]},
    With[{pwf = 
       Assuming[a0 < var < b0, 
        PiecewiseExpand[
         f /. dis : PlotPiecewise`$discontinuousAll[_] :> Piecewise[
            Map[
             {#[[1, -1]], 
               Replace[#[[2 ;;]], cond_ /; ! FreeQ[cond, C[_]] :>
                 (Reduce[#, var, 
                    DeleteDuplicates@Cases[#, C[_], Infinity]] & /@ 
                   LogicalExpand[
                    cond /. 
                    HoldPattern[And[e__?(FreeQ[#, var] &)]] :> 
                    Reduce[And[e]]])
                ]} &,

             List @@ 
              Reduce[dis == C[1] && C[1] ∈ Integers && 
                a0 < var < b0, {C[1], x}, Backsubstitution -> True]],
            Indeterminate], Method -> PlotPiecewise`pweMethods]]},
     If[Head[pwf] === Piecewise,
      PlotPiecewise`graphics = PlotPiecewise`plot[pwf, domain, opts],
      PlotPiecewise`graphics = 
       PlotPiecewise`plot[
        Piecewise[{{f, -Infinity < var < Infinity}}, Indeterminate], 
        domain, opts]]
     ]];
   PlotPiecewise`graphics
   ];
```

Comment: quite a nice answer!

Comment: It looks like this code could benefit from refactoring.  Would you care to work with me on that?

Comment: This is impressive. I'm baffled by the lack of ability to make common plots in Mathematica. :/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I went ahead and made some changes.  If you have something to suggest, I would welcome it.  Thanks!

Comment: I've been quite busy.  I see that you replaced the many `Part` operations, which were the primary things I wanted to change.  I'm sorry I missed an opportunity to work with you on this.

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. I robbed your code there to use for some graphs for limits. Thank you so much. A single upvote is not enough.

Comment: Can this function be made into a package? I had some trouble trying to do so.

Comment: @matan129 It should be possible.  I probably tried a long time ago before I knew what I was doing, probably in 1990s. Many of my early attempts at package-writing were frustrating and I gave up writing them for a while.

Answer (score 13):

### Update:

To overcome the issue I mention in [the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445/plot-discontinuous-function-with-black-and-white-disks-marking-discontinuities#comment118150_39462), also to make it more general, here is an upgraded version, which can deal with clipping and pointwise exclusion, and preserve styles specified in the original plot.

The main function is this `discontinuousHighlighter`:

```
Clear[discontinuousHighlighter]
discontinuousHighlighter[origplot_, {excluMarker_, clipMarker_}, radius_: 3] :=
 Module[{clipIntvX, black = Black, white, edgestyle},
        edgestyle = {AbsoluteThickness[1], black};
        white = If[# === None, White, #] &[Background /. AbsoluteOptions[origplot, Background]];
        (* clipped intervals: *)
        clipIntvX = Interval @@ Join @@ Cases[origplot,
                        {style___,lines:Longest[Line[_]..],___}/;Not[FreeQ[{style}, clipMarker]]:>{lines}[[All,1,All,1]],
                                              ∞];
        origplot /.
            (* exclusion boundary markers on curve: *)
            {style___, Point[pts__]} /; Not[FreeQ[{style}, excluMarker]] :>
             (black = If[# === {}, black, #[[-1]]] &@
                          DeleteCases[Cases[{style}, (RGBColor | Hue)[__], ∞], excluMarker];
              edgestyle = Join[edgestyle, {style /. Directive | EdgeForm -> Sequence} // Flatten];
              Flatten[{
                       EdgeForm[edgestyle],
                       FaceForm[white],
                       Module[{pt = #},
                              If[IntervalMemberQ[clipIntvX, pt[[1]]],
                                 {},
                                 Disk[pt, Offset[radius]]
                                ]
                          ] & /@ pts} /. excluMarker -> Sequence[]]
             ) /.
           (* exclusion markers on x axis: *)
           {style___, lines : (Line[_] ..)} /; FreeQ[{style}, clipMarker] && Not[FreeQ[{style}, excluMarker]] :>
            Join[
                 {style, lines} /. excluMarker -> Sequence[],
                 Flatten[{
                          EdgeForm[edgestyle],
                          FaceForm[black],
                          Disk[{Mean[#[[All, 1]]], 0}, Offset[radius]] & @@@ {lines}
                         }] /. excluMarker -> black
                ] /.
          (* clipped interval: *)
          {style___,lines:Longest[Line[_]..],post___}/;Not[FreeQ[{style},clipMarker]]&&Not[FreeQ[{post},clipMarker]] :>
           ({style, lines} /. clipMarker -> Sequence[]) //
          Show[#, PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]] &
       ]
```

Basically, we calculate the x coordinates of the filled disks from the exclusion lines, and convert the endpoints on curve to hollow disks.

To use the function, wrap `Plot[...]` with it:

```
Module[{excluMarker = RGBColor @@ RandomReal[1, 3], clipMarker = RGBColor @@ RandomReal[1, 3]},
       discontinuousHighlighter[
                                Plot[Exp[(Ceiling[Sin[x^2]] - 9/10) x] - 1.01, {x, -10, 10},
                                     PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3]],
                                     PlotPoints -> 1000, MaxRecursion -> 15,
                                     PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
                                     ExclusionsStyle -> {
                                                         Directive[GrayLevel[.8], Dashed, excluMarker],
                                                         Directive[EdgeForm[{Lighter[Purple]}], excluMarker]
                                                        },
                                     ClippingStyle -> Directive[Darker[Green], Thin, clipMarker],
                                     Background -> Lighter[Yellow, .9]
                                    ],
                                {excluMarker, clipMarker},
                                3 ]
      ]
```

[image: better result]

You can use any style in `ExclusionsStyle` and `ClippingStyle`. As long as they contain `excluMarker` and `clipMarker`, the result should be parsed correctly by `discontinuousHighlighter`. And hollow disks will automatically fit the background color.

### Original answer:

If you want to draw those disks and circles *automatically*, a convenient way would be post-processing a styled plot.

First we generate a unique mark for the `ExclusionsStyle` and `ClippingStyle`:

```
excluColor = RGBColor @@ RandomReal[1, 3];
clipColor = RGBColor @@ RandomReal[1, 3]
```

Use them to style the exclusions:

```
origplot = Plot[Floor[Tan[x]], {x, 0, π},
                PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick],
                Exclusions -> {Automatic, Cos[x] == 0},
                ExclusionsStyle -> {excluColor, excluColor}]
```

[image: original exclusion plot]

and the clipped intervals (we need this because the `ExclusionsStyle` seems to have a higher priority than `ClippingStyle`, and we don't want to mistake the clipped intervals for the discontinuous intervals):

```
clipplot = Plot[Floor[Tan[x]], {x, 0, π},
                Exclusions -> {Automatic, Cos[x] == 0},
                ExclusionsStyle -> None,
                ClippingStyle -> clipColor]

clipIntv = Interval @@ Cases[clipplot,
                             {___, clipColor, lines : (Line[_] ..)} :>
                                    Through[{Min, Max}@Flatten[#[[All, 1]] & @@@ {lines}]],
                             ∞];
```

To draw the circles correctly, we need to know the aspect-ratio and set a appropriate radius:

```
radius = 0.02;
{rgx, rgy} = PlotRange.{-1, 1} /. AbsoluteOptions[origplot, PlotRange];
asprat = AspectRatio /. AbsoluteOptions[origplot, AspectRatio];
```

The remaining work is some replacements:

```
origplot /.
  {excluColor, lines : (Line[_] ..)} :>
   Flatten[{Black, Module[{x = Mean[#[[All, 1]]]},
                          If[IntervalMemberQ[clipIntv, x],
                             {},
                             Disk[{x, 0}, radius {1, 1/asprat rgy/rgx}]
                            ]
                          ] & @@@ {lines}}] /.
 {excluColor, Point[pts__]} :>
  Flatten[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[White], Module[{pt = #},
                         If[IntervalMemberQ[clipIntv, pt[[1]]],
                            {},
                            Disk[pt, radius {1, 1/asprat rgy/rgx}]
                            ]
                        ] & /@ pts}] //
 Show[#, PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]] &
```

[image: discontinous points]

Comment: Nice! For discrete plots, one can also use `DiscretePlot` with `ExtentMarkers`

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks. There are still issues here. e.g. for `Plot[Exp[(Ceiling[Sin[x^2]]-9/10)x]-1,{x,0,10},PlotRange->{All,1}]`, some boundary points doesn't get circled. I'll try to fix it after lunch :)

Comment: Look up [`Offset[{dx, dy}`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Offset.html), the last entry under Details.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks, didn't know that! Will use it the next update.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tried the `Tooltip` way, but they sometimes change to something like `Tooltip[{}, "exclusion", TooltipStyle -> "TextStyling"]`, so I kept my `RGBColor` method. But `Offset[radius]` is really a great function. Thanks for the information!

Comment: @Silvia I'll delete the `Tooltip` comment then.  I like your way, because of the use of `Plot`'s automatic exclusion detection.  I wish there was a way to directly hook into it.

Comment: Thanks. It's a pity `Plot` cannot handle isolated discontinuous points (like `t==0` in your 3rd example), so it won't be able to perfectly solve the question. About the automatic exclusion detection, I guess there must be some internal functions dedicated for it, but `Trace` that would be really a hard work..

Comment: It's fantastic, discontinuousHighlighter will help me a lot. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you know a priori where are the discontinuities:

```
p = Plot[Sign[x + 0.5], {x, -1, 1}];
ap = AspectRatio /. AbsoluteOptions[p, AspectRatio]
epilog = {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], 
          Disk[{-1/2, -1}, .03 { ap, 1 }], Disk[{-1/2, 1}, .03 { ap, 1 }], 
          FaceForm[Black], Disk[{-1/2, 0}, .03 {ap, 1}]}; 

Plot[Sign[x + 0.5], {x, -1, 1}, Epilog -> epilog]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. This is great, but sadly, I may not know where discontinuities are. It would be great to generalise that; for more complicated functions it will be quite a hassle to specify these points. :(

Comment: On a related note, Wolfram|Alpha is able to create something very similar to what I'd like to:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discontinuities+of+sign%28x%2B0.5%29
(Meaning Mathematica should be able too.)

Comment: @user11426 `Plot[Sign[x + 0.5], {x, -1, 1}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, PointSize[Large]}]`

Comment: I hope it is possible and simple to do this automatically for those discontinuities that `Exclusions` already detects

Comment: Yay! This is near perfect! But lacks white points. :(