# How to draw dots at beginning and end of range when plotting

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I'm trying to plot a Piecewise function which should look like this:

[image: example]

How can I have similiar dots (filled or empty) at beginning and end of range?

```
F[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, -Infinity < x <= -4}, {0.2, -4 < x <= -2}, {0.5, -2 < x <= 2}, {0.9, 2 < x <= 6}}, 1]
Plot[F[x], {x, -6, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

This is how my plot looks like right now:

[image: how it looks now]

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445/plot-discontinuous-function-with-black-and-white-disks-marking-discontinuities/39466#39466

Comment: It worked, however I'm surprised it's not included as part of Mathematica and requires external functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Post-processing using custom `Arrowheads`:

```
g1 = Graphics[Disk[]];
g2 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[White], Disk[]}];

plt /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{{-.01, 0, g2}, {.0125, 1, g1}}], Arrow[x]}
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

One approach is to post-process the plot output to add filled and an empty circles to the lines:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{0, -Infinity < x <= -4}, {0.2, -4 < x <= -2}, 
                    {0.5, -2 < x <= 2}, {0.9, 2 < x <= 6}}, 1]
plt=Plot[f[x], {x, -6, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"];


plt/. Line[x_] :> {Line[x], AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[Last@x], 
       AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[First@x], 
      {White, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[First@x]}}
```

[image]

In version 9, you can specify the `PlotStyle` to add filled and empty circles to `Line` primitives (this trick doesn't seem to work in version 10):

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -6, 10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 PlotStyle -> ({#, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[Last @@ #], 
   Point[First @@ #], {White, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[First @@ #]}} &)]
```

[image]

```
f2[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2 - 5, -Infinity < x <= -4}, {x + 5, -4 <  x <= -2}, 
                    {10 - x^2, -2 < x <= 2}, {x^2 - 2 x - 4, 2 < x <= 6}}, 10]

Plot[f2[x], {x, -6, 10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 PlotStyle -> ({#, AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[Last @@ #], 
   Point[First @@ #], {White, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[First @@ #]}} &)]
```

[image]

Comment: It's much shorter solution than very long function in another thread. You could just reverse filled and empty dot - they should be opposite directed.

Comment: @stil, updated with the fix.

Comment: Very nice. I wonder if you could hide dot when function domain is out of axis bounds. For example, when there is domain between minus infinity and -4, and the x axis is just between -6 and 10, there shouldn't be any dot at x=-6.