# Does 'True' stand for 'Else' in Maximize function output?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, syntax, piecewise

```
Maximize[a x^2 + b x + c, x]
```

gives this solution:

[image]

Does the word `True` stand for "else" here? What exactly did `Maximize` return?

Comment: Yes it does....

Comment: Closely related [piecewise-function-explanation-of-extra-case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102259/piecewise-function-explanation-of-extra-case) It was a duplicate but many questions fit here rather than there. See also [155021](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155021/5478)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The right column is simply a list of conditions that define separate regimes of a `Piecewise` function. Since in principle these conditions could overlap, Mathematica determines the result of a `Piecewise` by checking the conditions from top to bottom, much as it does in `Which`. So if the condition is `True` it acts as a "catch-all" such that the corresponding value is chosen whenever none of the conditions above are true. This ensures that the `Piecewise` function always has a value. Therefore it has the same meaning as an "else" or "otherwise" you might read in "normal" mathematical notation of a piecewise function.