# What does True mean in this case?

Tags: piecewise

I use the following code to find the expansion for small $x$:

```
Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, 
 FullSimplify@
  Series[-Sqrt[-x] I^(n + 1/2) HankelH1[n, -x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

I find the solutions:

[image]

Analogously:

```
Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, 
 FullSimplify@
  Series[-Sqrt[-x] I^(n + 1/2) HankelH2[n, -x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

What does `True` mean in the last lines?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation of [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html):

> The $\text{cond}_i$ are evaluated in turn, until one of them is found to yield `True`.

The last condition is always `True`, so that `Piecewise` can return a value even when all the preceding conditions evaluated to `False`.

In a math textbook, this last case would be written as "otherwise".

---

When you write math notation for humans, you would make sure that the conditions are all disjoint, and there is an "otherwise" at the end.  A CAS like Mathematica needs to handle junk input reasonable gracefully.  What if some conditions overlap, or what if there's no "otherwise"?  Symbolically verifying that the conditions are disjoint is not feasible (not only is it a hard problem that is not solvable in general, it would be very slow in many cases when it *is* solvable). This is why Mathematica resorts to evaluating conditions in turn, and taking the first one that is `True`.  Additionally, it automatically adds a last `True` condition for "otherwise" if you haven't done so yourself.

Comment: I found this [109071](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109071/5478) which is not about `FullSimplify` but close enough for a duplicate. Do you mind if I close? No point in moving your well written answer I guess so let's leave it as a road sign.

Comment: @Kuba Feel free to close.