# Unfamiliar output of FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, piecewise

I got the following output of FullSimplify, when expecting to get "0".

[image: output]

I found no explanation of this output [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html).
 Could you please explain, what it means? That my expression equals zero when the condition $m^4 \Omega ^2 \sin ^2(\theta )+2 m r<r^2$ holds and that big fraction otherwise? Or maybe something else?

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102259/12  In that post, also look at the linked questions on the right.

Comment: @Szabolcs not necessarily. Perhaps `Piecewise` in general was unknown to OP.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP This has been asked several times before. There are many practically identical questions marked as a duplicate of that one (which is why I said look at the sidebar).  I agree that the answer there needs a slight updating to accommodate these better.  It can't me marked as a duplicate of a post that is already closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Szabolcs sorry, didn't read the last half of your comment `\_('')_/`

Comment: @Szabolcs well I've looked through the questions, and if anything is a duplicate, it's this one: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109071/26956 But I reckon the suggestion to inspect the `FullForm` when encountering an output you don't understand is more general. Not sure if vote to leave open or nominate this link as another duplicate.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP reopened

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> my expression equals zero when the condition `m4Ω2sin2(θ)+2mr<r2` holds and that big fraction otherwise?

Your assumption is correct. What you see is the typeset `OutputForm` of [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html).

Normally you can simply highlight an expression or a keyword, hit F1 and see the documentation page for it, but in this case it doesn't seem to work, so it's understandably unclear.

What you can do, however, is to run `FullForm@%` after you get a result like that. The output will be something like

```
Piecewise[ (* stuff *) ]
```

then you can realize that you need to look up `Piecewise`.