# Specify which is parameter in Maximize

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to use Maximize function
Maximize[{x^2 + y^2, a*x^4 + b *y^4 + c == 1}, {x, y}]
But I want Mathematica to consider only b to be the parameter, because a and c is only some constants (with many values). I need only to study how the maxima change with b.

Is there anyway to Mathematica which is parameters and which is constant? I tried to set the SetAttribute[a, Constant], but Mathematica still consider a to be parameter.
 hope someone can help.

Comment: Why isn't the result of `Maximize[{x^2 + y^2, a*x^4 + b*y^4 + c == 1}, {x, y}]` useful? You might want to add constraints to `a,b,c` as well; surely there are constraints for those constants too?

Comment: I just want to see the evolution of the maximum when the parameter b change. For example, a and c are material parameters and b is the applied force, which I can vary continuously. I have only 3 materials, so for each material, I consider a and c as constant and just want to check how the maximum change when the applied force changes.

Comment: also can you explain what is the meaning of True in the result of
Maximize[{x^2 + y^2, x^4 + a y^4 == 1}, {x, y}]
It does not mean that "this is always true". Why Mathematica don't just say " a<0"

Comment: The line with the `True` condition is the "otherwise" case; see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102259) for instance. You say that `a` and `c` are "material parameters", and `b` is a force. Can they be negative?

Comment: In my case all material parameters are positive. About force it can be negative. Thank

Comment: See, you had constraints on the constants after all! If so, you should be doing `Maximize[{x^2 + y^2, a*x^4 + b *y^4 + c == 1 && a > 0 && c > 0}, {x, y}]`.

Answer (score 1):

First solve for the y that fulfill the conditions in dependance of x
(since a and c are material parameters, I supposed them to be greater 0)

```
sol[x_, a_, b_, c_] = 
   Solve[a*x^4 + b*y^4 + c == 1 && a > 0 && c > 0, y, Reals]

(*     {{y -> ConditionalExpression[-((1 - c - a x^4)/b)^(
 1/4), (0 < a < (1 - c)/x^4 && 0 < c < 1 && b > 0 && 
   x > 0) || (0 < a < (1 - c)/x^4 && 0 < c < 1 && x < 0 && 
   b > 0) || (0 < c < 1 && b < 0 && a > (1 - c)/x^4 && 
   x > 0) || (0 < c < 1 && b < 0 && x < 0 && 
   a > (1 - c)/x^4) || (b < 0 && a > 0 && c > 1 && 
   x > 0) || (b < 0 && x < 0 && a > 0 && c > 1)]}, {y -> 
      ConditionalExpression[((1 - c - a x^4)/b)^(
1/4), (0 < a < (1 - c)/x^4 && 0 < c < 1 && b > 0 && 
   x > 0) || (0 < a < (1 - c)/x^4 && 0 < c < 1 && x < 0 && 
   b > 0) || (0 < c < 1 && b < 0 && a > (1 - c)/x^4 && 
   x > 0) || (0 < c < 1 && b < 0 && x < 0 && 
   a > (1 - c)/x^4) || (b < 0 && a > 0 && c > 1 && 
   x > 0) || (b < 0 && x < 0 && a > 0 && c > 1)]}}     *)
```

Calculate the xmax depending on a,b,c

```
xmax[a_, b_, c_] = 
    x /. Maximize[x^2 + y^2 /. sol[x, a, b, c][[1]], x][[2]]
```

[image]

(Maximize of course also gives you the hight of the maximum, not shown here)

For example plot for a=1 ond c=1/2

```
Plot[xmax[1, b, 1/2], {b, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[y /. sol[xmax[1, b, 1/2], 1, b, 1/2], {b, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

At last, consider, that there are two equal maxima, one at xmax and one at -xmax.
Have a look with

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[Evaluate[x^2 + y^2 /. sol[x, a, b, c][[1]]], {x, -1, 1}], {{a, 
       1}, -3, 3}, {{b, 1}, -4, 4}, {{c, 1/2}, -3, 3}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. Although this is not my purpose, but your answer is very informative for me.   interwhat

Comment: Actually, I recognize that Mathematica can not give answer to optimize a function vs a parameter while you tell it to ignore other  parameters. I think it is impossible, mathematically, because the number of solution and the solution value depend on the condition of all parameters.