# Excluding discontinuities in graphs

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to make some `ParametricPlot` and `ParametricPlot3D` of functions are singular but because *Mathematica* insists on drawing the asymptotic lines (i.e. connecting the infinities) it makes the pictures confusing. As an example take the function $\frac{1}{1-x}$, there is a vertical line at 1. Supposedly, the option `Exclusions -> True` should fix that, but that doesn't work for me.

Edit: For more concreteness, here is the mid-level difficulty thing I'm trying to plot:

```
R = 3;
X0 = {0, 0};
X = {t, x};
Cv = {0, -(1/(2 R))};
η = {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}};

Manipulate[Xhyp = {s, -Sqrt[α^2 + s^2]}; 
 Xsph = (Xhyp - Xhyp.η.Xhyp Cv)/(1 - 2 Xhyp.η.Cv + Xhyp.η.Xhyp Cv.η.Cv) + 2 R^2 Cv; 
 ParametricPlot[{Xsph[[2]], Xsph[[1]]}, {s, -r, r}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3 R, 3 R}, {-3 R, 3 R}}, Exclusions -> True],
 {r, 0.1, 100}, {{α, 10}, 0.1, 10}]
```

As you can see for small enough alpha and big enough the `r`, after the hyperbola on the left, it comes back from the other side and *Mathematica* draws the asymptotic lines. Those are what I want to get rid of.

Comment: `Exclusions -> {x = 1}`

Comment: @Feyre Yes, that would work for this simple example, but what I'm looking for is for Mathematica to do this on its own. The actual functions I want to plot are complicated, I don't know exactly where the singularities are.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: `Exclusions -> {1/f[x] == 0}`?  If not, you might need to edit the question to include a typical example.

Comment: Can't you make a function in the vein of `Exclusions -> {x - 1 == 0}`

Comment: Maybe look at [this question and set of answers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445/plot-a-piecewise-function-with-black-and-white-disks-marking-discontinuities). (Of course, these aren't for parametric plots, which makes it much more difficult, but it's perhaps a start.)

Comment: Like @MichaelE2 said, I was doing it and now see his comment. `Clear[f, x]
f = 1/((x - 1) (x - 4) (x - 5));
poles = Solve[1/f == 0, x];
poles = poles /. Rule -> Equal;
Plot[f, {x, -5, 5}]
Plot[f, {x, -5, 5}, Exclusions -> poles]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4vJ1U.png)

Comment: @Nasser One advantage (maybe simultaneously, a weakness?) to `Exclusions -> 1/f == 0` is that I believe `Plot` will break the graph whenever `f` changes sign, so that it doesn't have to be an equation that can be solved. (It still works on even-order poles, because they leave the plot range.)

Comment: `Exclusions -> {1/Xsph[[2]] == 0, 1/Xsph[[1]] == 0}` works if you simplify `Xsph` first: `Xsph = Simplify[..<your formula here.>..]`  (I think there's a common factor to be canceled.)