# A discontinuity in a plot of a continuous function

Tags: plotting, discontinuity

I plot a continuous, though not a smooth function:

```
Plot[If[a >= 0.5, 0, Sqrt[0.5 - a]], {a, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

which returns the following

[image: plot]

One can see the discontinuity at `a=0.5`. It should not be there.
Any idea of how to remove it and why it shows up?

Comment: @Manu  Thank you. What does it do?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (neither in a notebook, not after exporting). What's your `$Version`?

Comment: Recommend that you use [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) rather than [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.htmlf2'[a]) for mathematical functions. `Plot[Piecewise[{{Sqrt[1/2 - a], a < 1/2}}], {a, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> None]`

Comment: interesting, in 10.1, even with `MaxRecursion->0` you still get a connected line.  The gap indicates the function is evaluating undefined (/complex) This may be a bug.

Comment: @corey979 The version is 11.0.0.0 In the previous version of Mma the problem did not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the automatic expansion of `Exclusions` is evolving.  Currently (V11.0.1 for me), it seems that when a function changes formulas -- for example, through `Piecewise`, `UnitStep`, `if`, etc. -- the changes are treated as singularities without checking whether the function is finite at the "singular" point or whether the two formulas are continuous with each other. Consequently, such points are excluded. The difficulty is, I assume, in determining the two values the function approaches as the input approaches the singular point from each side.  It can be tricky, given that the user supplies the code for the function and there isn't always a convenient way to determine the limits of the function.  (Related: [Plot a piecewise function with black and white disks marking discontinuities](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445/plot-a-piecewise-function-with-black-and-white-disks-marking-discontinuities/39466#39466)).

The "issue" arises because `If[]` was originally a programming construct and `Piecewise[]` was a function construct. In earlier versions of *Mathematica*, the discontinuity procession of `If[]` was not as complete as that for `Piecewise[]`.  I suspect it is because users are familiar with "if" from other programming languages, and consequently many use `If[]` instead of `Piecewise[]`, that `If[]` is becoming more and more equivalent to `Piecewise[]`.

So what you see in the new(er) versions is the extension of discontinuity processing in plots of `If[cond, e1, e2]` to exclude points where `cond` changes value.

The principal solution is to manually override [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html), as [suggested by Manu](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139943/a-discontinuity-in-a-plot-of-a-continous-function#comment377783_139943) and [Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139943/a-discontinuity-in-a-plot-of-a-continous-function#comment377798_139943):

```
Plot[If[a >= 0.5, 0, Sqrt[0.5 - a]], {a, -1, 1},
 Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> {-0.01, 0.1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `MaxRecursion -> 15` makes the discontinuity "disappear" by excessive refinement, but the discontinuity is still present if you zoom in:

```
Plot[If[a >= 0.5, 0, Sqrt[0.5 - a]], {a, -1, 1},
 MaxRecursion -> 15, PlotRange -> {-0.001, 0.01}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

In V11, `Exclusions -> userExclusions` is handled internally by a new function

```
Visualization`ExpandExclusions[{functions}, {variables}, userExclusions]
```

In V10, V9 and perhaps earlier, `Exclusions` are handled by

```
Visualization`VisualizationDiscontinuities[{functions}, {variables}]
```

`` Visualization`ExpandExclusions `` expands the discontinuities of the OP's function:

```
Visualization`ExpandExclusions[{If[a >= 0.5`, 0, Sqrt[0.5` - a]]}, {a}, Automatic]
(*  {{0.5 - a == 0, True}, {-0.5 + a == 0, True}}  *)
```

`` Visualization`VisualizationDiscontinuities `` does not (in V9-11):

```
Visualization`VisualizationDiscontinuities[{If[a >= 0.5`, 0, Sqrt[0.5` - a]]}, {a}]
(*  {}  *)
```

But it will if the `If[]` is converted to a `Piecewise` function:

```
Visualization`VisualizationDiscontinuities[{
  PiecewiseExpand@If[a >= 0.5`, 0, Sqrt[0.5` - a]]}, {a}]
(*  {{0.5 - Re[a] <= 0, -Im[a] == 0}, {True, -0.5 + a == 0}, {True, 0.5 - a == 0}}  *)
```

In this last case, in V9+, the plot of `PiecewiseExpand@If[..]` will contain a gap at `a == 0.5`.  However, it does not appear that `` Visualization`ExpandExclusions `` uses `PiecewiseExpand`, so it may not be equivalent.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is :

```
Plot[If[a >= 0.5, 0, Sqrt[0.5 - a]], {a, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All,  PlotPoints -> 2000]
```

The resulted plot is :

[image: Plot of the function with higher PlotPoints]

Increasing the `PlotPoints` attribute may help the `Plot` to draw a smooth curve over discontinuities in piecewise functions.

Comment: It makes the discontinuity imperceptible, unless you zoom in: `Show[plot, PlotRange -> {{0.499, 0.501}, Automatic}, Frame -> True]`