# Missing point while plotting

Tags: plotting

[image: I though I will get a point at f(2)=6, anyone please help me I am new on programming, Thanks]

I though I will get a point at f(2)=6, anyone please help me I am new on programming, Thanks

Comment: `Plot` works by discretely sampling the function. This would only work in the unlikely event `Plot` happens to sample exactly at `x=2`.  Best bet here is to just use `Epilog->Point[{2,6}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange.  In order to learn how to use this site 
[take the tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). When copying equations from a notebook to your question one should format using inline code  by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is recommended that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: Use the code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39466/29734) and do `PlotPiecewise[Piecewise[{{2^x, x != 2}, {6, x == 2}}], {x, -1, 3}]`.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your piecewise function, but Mathematica's plotting algorithm really can't show an intervals are less than single pixel. A single real number, which has measure zero, simply doesn't show up. There are ways to deal with the problem. Here are two. One of them may be what you want.

#### Force Plot to draw the point.

```
pw1[x_] := Piecewise[{{2^x, x != 2}}, 6]
Plot[pw1[ x], {x, -1, 3}, Epilog -> {Point[{2, pw1[2]}]}]
```

[image: pw1]

#### Redefine the function so it takes the value 6 over a large enough interval.

```
With[{d = .015},
  With[{span = 2 + {-1, 1} d},
    pw2[x_] := Piecewise[{{6, Between[x, span]}}, 2^x]]]
Plot[pw2[x], {x, -1, 3}, PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image: pw2]

Note that I had to ask for extra plot points to get the small interval to show up.