# Defining a function with a point of finite discontinuity

Tags: function-construction, piecewise, discontinuity

I wrote the code for the function $T$ defined on $[0,1]$ by $T(x)=\frac{x+2}{3}$ if $x\neq\frac{1}{2}$ and $T(\frac{1}{2})=1$ as follows.

```
T[x_] := If[x != 1/2, (2*x + 1)/3, 1];
```

I am not sure if the code I wrote defines the function $T$ correctly as the command `Plot' fails to highlight the discontinuity at $\frac{1}{2}$.

A clarification to my doubt will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Probably better to use `Piecewise[]`

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Use `Piecewise` and see the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445/plot-a-piecewise-function-with-black-and-white-disks-marking-discontinuities).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot a piecewise function with black and white disks marking discontinuities](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445/plot-a-piecewise-function-with-black-and-white-disks-marking-discontinuities)

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{(x + 2)/3, x != 1/2}, {1, x == 1/2}}]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Dotted, Directive[Black, AbsolutePointSize[5]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Bob Hanlon. Thanks for fixing my typo.

Comment: To show the actual value at the discontinuity: `Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Dotted, Directive[White, AbsolutePointSize[3]]}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{1/2, f[1/2]}]}]`