# Dots at points of discontinuity

Tags: piecewise, discontinuity

So, I got this code:

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{3, x <= 0}, {x^2 + 1, x > 0}}], {x, -2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Purple}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]
```

and I want to add full dot at 0 from the left and partial at 0 from the right. I hope you know what I mean. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot a piecewise function with black and white disks marking discontinuities](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445/plot-a-piecewise-function-with-black-and-white-disks-marking-discontinuities)

Comment: to the close voters, the requirement _***"full dot at 0 from the left and partial at 0 from the right"***_ makes this  question different from the linked q/a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{3, x <= 0}, {x^2 + 1, x > 0}}]
rval = Limit[f[x], x -> 0, Direction -> -1];
Plot[
 f[x],
 {x, -2, 2},
 PlotStyle -> {Purple},
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> True,
 Epilog -> {
   {PointSize[0.03], Purple, Point@{0, f[0]}},
   {PointSize[0.03], Purple, Point@{0, rval}},
   {White, PointSize[0.02], Point@{0, rval}}
 }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can construct the desired marker using `Disk` and `Circle`:

```
halfdisk[color1_, color2_: White] := {Thickness[0.1], 
   EdgeForm[color1], color2,  Disk[{0, 0}, 1],
   color1, Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {π/2, -(π/2)}], Circle[{0, 0}]};
```

and use it with `Inset` as `Epilog` option in `Plot`:

```
epilog = {Inset[Graphics@halfdisk[Purple, Purple], {0, 1}, Automatic, Scaled[.05]],
      Inset[Graphics@halfdisk[Purple], {0, 3}, Automatic, Scaled[.05]]};

Plot[Piecewise[{{3, x <= 0}, {x^2 + 1, x > 0}}], {x, -2, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Purple, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  Epilog -> epilog]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
fn = Piecewise[{{3, x <= 0}, {x^2 + 1, x > 0}}];

p1 = Plot[fn, {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Purple}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True];

p2 = ListPlot[{{0, Limit[fn, x -> 0, Direction -> #]}} & /@ {1, -1}, PlotStyle -> Purple,
     PlotMarkers -> (Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 10] & /@ {Disk[{0, 0}, 1], DiskSegment[{0, 0}, 1, {Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}]} )];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]