# Showing a point on a plot as a circle rather than a disk

Tags: plotting

Consider the following code:

```
f[x_] = Which[x <= 1, x^3 + 3 x^2 - 2, x > 1, 4]

Show[
  Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 4}],
  ListPlot[{{1, f[1]}}], 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 6}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Point[{{1, f[1]}}]}]
```

I get a plot of the discontinuous function $f(x)$.

I would like to ask you if there is a way to show the point of discontinuity on the plot of `f`, without it being displayed as a black disk. I would like it displayed as a circle.

Comment: [A related thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend plotting the function like this:

```
f[x_] = Which[x <= 1, x^3 + 3 x^2 - 2, x > 1, 4]

Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 4}], 
 ListPlot[{{1, Limit[f[x], x -> 1, Direction -> "FromAbove"]}}, 
  PlotMarkers -> "OpenMarkers"], 
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 6}},
 AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

The open marker signifies the left end point is *not* plotted on the second interval.  The `Limit` function is used to calculate the point.

[image]

Comment: +1 I like the plot marker more than using the disk, so removing my answer.

Comment: @LouisB's code is elegant and plots the function correctly, but in your original plot the point is highlighted when x == 1.  If you want an open circle at that location, just change the limit direction to "FromBelow".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but when I copy and paste your code on the notebook, only the empty circle appears.... and the graph of $f$. What is wrong there?

Comment: @dmtri    My first thought is you should start with a new notebook and a fresh kernel, or `Clear` your variables.  Can you be more explicit about what is missing?  Maybe edit your question and add a new paragraph with your latest code and and a picture of the graph.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it using the `Disk` graphics primitive. It is similar to Nasser's deleted answer, but with the difference that I use `ColorData[97]` to make the color of the marker match the curve, and I use `Offset` to fix the aspect ratio issue. (No matter what aspect ratio you're using, the disk will stay circular.)

```
f[x_] := Which[x <= 1, x^3 + 3 x^2 - 2, x > 1, 4]

Plot[
 f[x], {x, -4, 4},
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 6}},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y},
 Epilog -> {
   EdgeForm[{Thick, ColorData[97, 1]}], FaceForm[White],
   Disk[{1, f[1]}, Offset[{4, 4}]]
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]