# How to plot HeavisideTheta with y=0.5 at x=0, and similar piecewise functions

Tags: plotting, piecewise

How does one plot piecewise functions, with the ability to plot individual points along with open points to clearly show how values are defined at discontinuities?

Example:

[image]
[Image Credit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dirac_distribution_CDF.png)

with the dashed vertical line omitted.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445/plot-a-piecewise-function-with-black-and-white-disks-marking-discontinuities

Comment: This plot makes no sense in traditional math, since  the so-called `HeavisideTheta` function is not a usual function, but a distribution (i.e. a certain functional).

Comment: @user64494 and yet that doesn't matter a lick for the OP

Comment: @b3m2a1: The plot under consideration is a plot of a piecewise function, not `HeavisideTheta`. Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 2):

Something to get you started

```
Plot[HeavisideTheta[x], {x, -1, 1}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> None,
 Epilog -> {
   {
    FaceForm[None],
    EdgeForm[ColorData[97][1]],
    Disk[{0, 1}, .025]
    },
   {
    ColorData[97][1],
    Disk[{0, .5}, .025]
    },
   {
    FaceForm[None],
    EdgeForm[ColorData[97][1]],
    Disk[{0, 0}, .025]
    }
   },
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't find the elegant way to  **un-clipped** or **un-filled** the point,so I have to use `White`.

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1/2, x == 0}}, HeavisideTheta[x]];
Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, 
 Epilog -> {Style[Point[{0, 1/2}], PointSize[Large], Blue], 
   Style[Point[{0, 1}], PointSize[Large], Green], 
   Style[Point[{0, 1}], PointSize[Medium], White], 
   Style[Point[{0, 0}], PointSize[Large], Cyan], 
   Style[Point[{0, 0}], PointSize[Medium], White]}, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]