# How to make the segmentation function automatically draw the correct function image at the break point?

Tags: plotting, piecewise, discontinuity

**The function is:**

We know that f[x] is an even function defined on x < 0 And x > 0,

when `x > 0`,

`0 < x <= 2, Abs[x-1]`,

`x > 2, 1/2 f[x - 2]`

There is a problem with drawing an image of f[x] with the following code, see image drawing red circle

```
f[x_] := 
 Which[0 < x <= 2, Abs[x - 1], x > 2, 1/2 f[x - 2], x < 0, f[-x]]
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 10}]
```

[image]

The correct image looks like this, and notice that the images at the demarcation point are not connected

[image]

How to make the segmentation function automatically draw the correct function image at the break point?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39445 There are a couple answers that seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now you could do this workaround but this can be automated if needed. Left as an exercise.

```
f[x_] := Which[0 < x < 2, Abs[x - 1], x > 2, 1/2  f[x - 2],x < 0, f[-x]]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> Range[2, 10, 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can add

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, Exclusions -> Range[2, 10, 2], 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

If you define your function such that it contains the discontinuities then Mma will automatically exclude them.

The function is piecewise right continuous with modulo 2 step size and vertical shrinking factor of $\frac{1}{2}^n$ where $n$ is the number of steps.

First define the base function with the left side discontinuity.

```
f1[x_] :=
 Piecewise[{
   {Abs[x - 1], 0 < x <= 2}
   , {Indeterminate, True}
   }]
```

Next apply the modulo 2 step size and the step dependent shrinking factor.

```
f2[x_] := f1[Mod[Abs[x], 2]]/(2^Floor[Abs[x]/2])
```

Mathematica will automatically exclude the discontinuities.  You only need provide an exclusion style if you want to show them.

```
Plot[f2[x], {x, -1, 10}, ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashing[Small], None}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.