# How to automatically draw the solid point and circle not including this point at the interval discontinuity point of the piecewise function image?

Tags: plotting

[How to make the segmentation function automatically draw the correct function image at the break point?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/298153/how-to-make-the-segmentation-function-automatically-draw-the-correct-function-im)

Through the above problem post solved the problem of software drawing solid line at the interval discontinuity point of the piecewise function.

```
f[x_] := 
 Which[0 < x < 2, Abs[x - 1], x > 2, 1/2   f[x - 2], x < 0, f[-x]]
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 10}, Exclusions -> Range[2, 10, 2], 
 ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

Now there is a problem, at the endpoint of the piecewise interval, a certain image includes the point corresponding to the interval endpoint, and a certain image does not include the point corresponding to the interval endpoint, which should be identified as a circle in the image. But the software automatically identifies it as a solid point that can be taken.

How can we set up the software to automatically draw a circle at the point of the corresponding function image that can not be taken?

[image]

According to the correct image, the position of the red circle in the top image, i.e. the point where the interval endpoint is not reachable, should be marked as a circle. How to set up so that the software can automatically mark as a circle at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sometimes it is easier to make custom solution than general one.

```
endPoint = 8;
xpoints = Range[0, endPoint, 2];
f[x_] := Which[0 <= x < 2, Abs[x - 1], x >= 2, 1/2    f[x - 2], x < 0, f[-x]];
ypoints = f[#] & /@ xpoints;
xypoints = Transpose[{xpoints, ypoints}];
p = {EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], FaceForm[White]};
ep = {Sequence @@ p, Disk[#, Scaled[.01]] & /@ xypoints};
vlines = {Dashed, Line[{#, {#[[1]], 0}}] & /@ xypoints};
hlines = Line[{{-1, #[[2]]}, {endPoint, #[[2]]}}] & /@ xypoints;
```

Now

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 10},
 Exclusions -> xpoints,
 ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed,
 ImageSize -> 400,
 Epilog -> {vlines, hlines, ep}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Feel free to make adjustments as needed.