# How do I avoid the gaps introduced by a frame on a plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

You can see that there are gaps on all sides of the plot between the frame and the extent of the line that I've plotted. How do I get rid of these? I'd like the frame to cover $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and no more.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

> [image]

Comment: One way is to specify `PlotRange` as in `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks This also works; thanks!

Comment: Related: [(3618)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3618/121), [(7453)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7453/121), [(9346)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9346/121)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The key to the solution was [`PlotRangePadding -> 0`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRangePadding.html).

Comment: Whoops, I missed that. I was looking for options relating to `Frame`. Thanks!

Comment: @Will I understand; there are *a lot* of options, especially for plotting and graphics.

Comment: PlotRangePadding->0 did not quite eliminate the white space in my ContourPlot and StreamPlot, but PlotRangePadding->-0.02 did.

Comment: @Sander That's a bit unexpected in the case of `ContourPlot`; which version are you using, and is it with every plot or specific code?  `StreamPlot` does seem to leave some extra space so a negative padding value makes more sense there.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are right, the ContourPlot on its own does not leave white space with 0 padding. The white space on it was due to overlaying with the previous StreamPlot using Show[]. I guess it inherited the StreamPlot's padding.