# BarChart FrameLabels with only partial Frame?

Tags: graphics

This test BarChart is generated by the code that follows it:

[image]

```
data = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 10}], {3}, {4}];

BarChart[MapThread[Labeled[#1, #2, Above] &, {data, {1, 2, 3}}], 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartStyle -> 
  Reverse@{Lighter@Blue, Blue, Darker@Blue, Darker@Darker@Blue}, 
 ChartLabels -> {{"a", "b", "c"}, None},
 Frame -> {False, True, False, False},
 FrameLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14}]
```

Since only a y-axis component of Frame is rendered: `Frame -> {False, True, False, False}`
the "x axis" label of `FrameLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis"}` is omitted - and that's consistent with documentation.

Is it possible to display "x axis" at the location it would be if the bottom component of the Frame were there *and* preserving the set `BaseStyle` values (eg `Font`, `FontSize`)?

This can be done using `Inset` but positioning is ad-hoc and it does not preserve `BaseStyle` values.

Wrapping `Labeled` around `Barchart` doesn't correctly center the text and moreover does not use the `BaseStyle` values, as the following screenshot shows. Here for comparison the bottom component of Frame is True - and note the disastrous clash of graphical elements.

[image]

Finally, using the bottom `Frame` component: `Frame -> {True, True, False, False}` but without ticks: `FrameTicks -> {None, Automatic, None, None}` results in an ugly double axis and overlap in labels:

[image]

Any other options, eg using `LabelingFunction`?

Comment: Related: [(18807)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18807/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the overlaid ticks by using `FrameTicksStyle` to set them to `Transparent` and remove the doubled edge by setting `PlotRangePadding` to `None`, like so:

```
BarChart[MapThread[Labeled[#1, #2, Above] &, {data, {1, 2, 3}}], 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartStyle -> 
  Reverse@{Lighter@Blue, Blue, Darker@Blue, Darker@Darker@Blue}, 
 ChartLabels -> {{"a", "b", "c"}, None}, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {Automatic, Transparent}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, FrameLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14}]
```

Or you could explicitly set the `FrameTicks` to something invisible but that takes up the same vertical spacing you want, like so:

```
BarChart[MapThread[Labeled[#1, #2, Above] &, {data, {1, 2, 3}}], 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartStyle -> 
  Reverse@{Lighter@Blue, Blue, Darker@Blue, Darker@Darker@Blue}, 
 ChartLabels -> {{"a", "b", "c"}, None}, 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {{{1, ""}}, None}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, FrameLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14}]
```