# Beginner's question: Gap between FrameLabel and BarChart

Tags: plotting

I have a BarChart (Mathematica 9.0.1)

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3},
ChartLabels -> (Rotate[Text[Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]]], -Pi/2]
& /@{abcdabcd,abcdabcd, abcdabcd})]
```

[image]

and would like to add a vertical label to the y-axis. I tried

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3},
ChartLabels -> (Rotate[Text[Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]]], -Pi/2]
& /@ {abcdabcd, abcdabcd, abcdabcd}),
FrameLabel -> {None, "y-axis"},
Frame -> {False, True, False, False}]
```

and it's perfect except for a gap between the two axes (which is somehow extremely ugly with the actual data):

[image]

I tried using Labeled, but then the label is positioned too low (i want it at the center of the y-axis):

```
Labeled[BarChart[{1, 2, 3},
ChartLabels -> (Rotate[Text[Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]]], -Pi/2]
& /@ {abcdabcd, abcdabcd, abcdabcd})],
{Rotate[Style["y-axis", FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], Pi/2]}, {Left}]
```

(Can't post > 2 links)

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: Welcome, Stefan.  I embedded the images for you.  The image/link limitation is an anti-spam measure that will be lifted once you start using the site more.

Comment: @Silvia: If I try that, the gap is gone, but so is the label ('y-axis').

Comment: Oops, you're right. Sorry for my oversight..

Comment: Related: [(18807)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18807/121), [(19893)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19893/121)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second attempt (which results in the gap), you can remove the gap by eliminating the `PlotRangePadding` for the x-axis.

```
PlotRangePadding -> {0, 0}
```

Comment: You're right, that's even a bit simpler than Mr. Wizards solution.

Comment: @Stefan For what it's worth the output (from this) looks a bit different on version 7, and the longer code was required to match your output.  Also, I believe you should be able to use the slightly shorter `PlotRangePadding -> 0` to produce the same output as given by `PlotRangePadding -> {0, 0}`.

Answer (score 1):

This feels a lot more complicated than it should be, but I think at least it works:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3},
 ChartLabels ->
  (Rotate[Text[Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]]], -Pi/2] & /@ {abcdabcd, abcdabcd, abcdabcd}),
 FrameLabel -> {None, "y-axis"},
 Frame -> {1, 1, 0, 0},
 FrameTicks -> {None, All},
 PlotRangePadding -> {0.1, 0}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what a needed.