# BarChart: Want to rotate and place a y-axis label on the left side

Tags: plotting, labeling, charts

I would like to know if it's posible to place the y-axis label roated on the left side without using `Frame->True` and `FrameLabel-> {"txt1", "txt2"}`

My command:

```
BarChart[{{0.123, 0.492}, {2.865, 0.055}, {1.03, 1.084}, {4.282, 0.053}},
   AxesLabel -> {"", Rotate["Value", 90 Degree]}, 
   ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"},
     {{0.5, 0}, {0.8, 1.2}}, Rotate[#, (1.75/7) Pi] &], 
     Placed[{"", ""}, Above]}, 
   LabelingFunction -> (
     Placed[Rotate[#, 0.5 Pi], If[#1 > 0.5, Center, Above]] &),
   ChartLegends -> {"⌀", "σ"}
]
```

The result:
[image: Example1]

As you can see the label gets rotated. However, I was unable to place it at 50% vertically. Furthermore I've tried

```
AxesLabel->{"",Placed[Rotate["Value",0.5 Pi],Center]}
```

without success.

Using a `Frame` would be on option, but doing so removes the "grouping" in my `BarChart`:

.

[image: Example2]

According to [Placing x-axes label below rather than at end of axes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/placing-x-axes-label-below-rather-than-at-end-of-axes) `Labeled` could be on Option too. But again, I was not able to center the label:

```
Labeled[bar,Rotate["Values",0.5Pi],{{Center,Left}}]
```

Comment: It is possible to do `Frame->{False,True,False,False},Axes->{True,False},PlotRangePadding->None` to keep your x axis and use only the frame on the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks you @N.J.Evans - That's what I was looking for.
Is there a way to mark this question as solved without a "real answer"?

Comment: Related: [(19893)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19893/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, adding `Frame->{False,True,False,False},Axes->{True,False},PlotRangePadding->None` to keep your x axis and use only the frame on the y-axis should work.

```
BarChart[{{0.123, 0.492}, {2.865, 0.055}, {1.03, 1.084}, {4.282, 
   0.053}}
 , AxesLabel -> {None, Rotate["Value", 90 Degree]}
 , ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"data1", "data2", "data3", 
     "data4"}, {{0.5, 0}, {0.8, 1.2}}, Rotate[#, (1.75/7) Pi] &], 
   Placed[{"", ""}, Above]}
 , LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Rotate[#, 0.5 Pi], 
     If[#1 > 0.5, Center, Above]] &)
 , ChartLegends -> {"⌀", "σ"}
 , PlotRangePadding -> None
 , Frame -> {False, True, False, False}
 , Axes -> {True, False}
 , FrameLabel -> {None, "y-Axis"}
 ]
```

[image]