# How to eliminate the margin between figure and frame in DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

In `DensityPlot`, how to get rid of the white margin between the figure and the frame so that the figure itself spans the entire domain?

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {20, 20}}, 
  ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}]
```

[image: sin(xy)]

Comment: `PlotRangePadding -> 0`

Comment: It should be noted that specifying non-negative values for `PlotRangePadding` does not reduce the domain of a plot. It ***extends*** the domain so as to include the requested padding. You will see no more of your plot by setting `PlotRangePadding` to zero or `None`. You will just make the ticks harder to see.

Comment: @m_goldberg  On that note, I became curious about following: Is it possible to reverse the ticks so they point outward?

Comment: @joojaa yes. look up `Ticks` in the docs.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch could you vote as a duplicate of: [18807](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18807/5478). I've lost my vote, which is retracted now, for "simple mistake".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
    DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {20, 20}}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]